# sk.learn average_precision_score

Tags: scikit-learn, average-precision

[sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1luZb.png)

The average precision score calculate in the sklearn function follows the formula shown below and in the attached image.

```
        AP = Σ(Rn - Rn-1)Pn *The index value of the sumation is n. Please refer to the attached image for a clear version of the formula
```

I am struggling to fully understand the math behind this function. I am particularly curious about how the nth thresholds in the formula are calculated. Are the number of thresholds equivalent to the number of samples?

Answer (score 0):

The number of thresholds is *at most* equal to the number of samples as several samples may have the same underlying continuous value from the classifier.

As for the math, the precision-recall curve has recall on the abscissa and precision on the ordinata. So this is basically just an approximation of the area under the precision-recall curve where (Rn-Rn-1) is the width of the rectangle while Pn is the height. It's kind of like AUC only for the precision-recall curve instead of the ROC curve.